# How to send massive data of sensors in Orion

Tags: fiware, fiware-orion

Let's suppose to have 100 sensors that send an attribute any second to Orion. How could I manage this massive data?

1. via batch operation (but I don't know if it can support them)
2. using an edge (to aggregate data) and sending to Orion (after 1 minute)

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Let’s consider 100 tps a high load for a given infrastructure (load and throughput must be always related to infrastructure and e2e scenarios).

The main problem you may encounter is not related to the update itself, Orion Context Broker and its fork Orion LD, can handle a lot of updates. The main problem in real/productive scenarios, like the ones handled by Orion Context Broker and NGSI v2, are the NOTIFICATIONS related to those UPDATES.

If you need a 1:1 (or even a 1:2 or 1:4) ratio between UPDATES:NOTIFICATIONS, for example you want to keep track of the history of every measure and also send the measures to the CEP for some post-processing, then it’s not only a matter of how many updates Orion may handle, but how many update-notifications the E2E can handle. If you got a slow notification endpoint Orion will saturate its notification queues and you will be losing notifications (not keeping track of those updates within en historic, or CEP…).

Batch updates are not helping on this since the UPDATE REQUEST SERVER is not the bottleneck and they are internally managed as single updates.

To alleviate this problem I should recommend you to enable NGSI V2 (only available in V2) [flow control mechanism](https://github.com/telefonicaid/fiware-orion/blob/master/doc/manuals/admin/perf_tuning.md#updates-flow-control-mechanism), so the update process may be automatically slowed down when the notification throughput requires so.

**And of course, in any IoT scenario if you don’t need all the data the earlier you aggregate the better. So if your E2E doesn’t need to keep track of every single measure, data loggers are more than welcome.**

Answer (score 1):

For 100 sensors sending one update per second (did I understand that correctly?) ... that's nothing. The broker can handle 2-3 thousand updates per second running in a single core and with ~4 GB of RAM (mongodb needs about 3 times that).
And, if it's more (a lot more), then yes, the NGSI-LD API defines batch operations (for Create, Update, Upsert, and Delete of entities), and Orion-LD implements them all.

However, there's no batch op for attribute update. You'd need to use "batch update entity", the *update* mode (not *replace*). Check the NGSI-LD API spec for details.